# fadeIn() and fadeOut() innerhtml

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have rephrased my question so people can understand.

I want to smoothly change the text that is inside of a div I have. However, when I try the code, the injected contents show prematurely. They show the new innerHTML and then fade out and fade in. Can anyone assist me in knowing why this happens so I can solve this? Thank you!

code:

```
case 3:
    $("#cont").fadeOut()
    $("#cont").html("<p>Hello!!!!3</p>").fadeIn();  
    break;
case 4:
    $("#cont").fadeOut()
    $("#cont").html("<p>Hello!!!!4</p>").fadeIn();
    break;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the `call back` function,

```
case 3:
    $("#cont").fadeOut(400,function(){
      $(this).html("<p>Hello!!!!3</p>").fadeIn();  
    });
    break;
```

Answer (score 0):

if you look at the documentation for the `fadeIn()` and `fadeOut()` functions, you'll notice that one of the parameters is `callback`. this parameter is a function that will be called *after* the fade is executed. try using this to control when your HTML is being changed.

Comment: Thank you, I will be sure to go over that.

Answer (score 0):

Hard without the full code, but try this:

```
var content = ''
switch(type){
  case 3:
      content = 'Hello!!!!3';
      break;
  case 4:
      content = 'Hello!!!!4';
      break;
}

 $("#cont")
   .stop() // cancel previous animations
   .fadeOut(400,
       function(){  // change text and fadeIn once fadeOut completes
          $("#cont")
              .html("<p>" + content + "</p>")
              .fadeIn(); 
       });
```